# Use data from Query in Controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

What can I have to change in my Symfony3 project to properly received data by Doctrine?

When I replace `-> findOneBy ('name' => $selName)` by my  **->MyQuery($selName)** I'll received `FatalThrowableError`:

"Call to a member function getName() on array 500 Internal Server Error"
line:

**->setGoalName ($dictSelRow->getName())**

but if use **findOneBy** is OK.

Repository:

```
class DictSelRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  /**
   * Function MyQuery
   * @param $selName
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function MyQuery( $selName )
  {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder( 'dg' )
      ->where( 'dg.name= :par1' )
      ->andWhere( 'dg.dateStart >= :now')
      ->andWhere( 'dg.dateEnd < :now')
      ->setParameter( 'par1', $selName )
      ->setParameter( 'now', new \DateTime() )
      ->getQuery()
      ->setMaxResults(1)
      ->getResult();
  }
}
```

From Controller

```
/**
 * Creates a new SeluRF entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="selu_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 *
 *
 * @Template
 */
public function newSeluRFAction( Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository( 'MyBundle:SeluRF' );
    $dictSelRow = $em
        // ->findOneBy( [ 'name' => 'X127a',]);
        ->dictGoalByTypeQuery( '1w' );

    $SeluRF = new SeluRF();
    $SeluRF
        ->setGoalName ($dictSelRow->getName())
        ->setGoalType ($dictSelRow->getType())
        ->setDateStart($dictSelRow->getDateStart())
        ->setDateEnd  ($dictSelRow->getDateEnd())
        ->setSymbolName($dictSelRow->getSymbolName())
    ;

    $form = $this->createForm('MyBundle\Form\SeluType', $SeluRF);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($SeluRF);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('selu_show', ['id' => $SeluRF->getId()]);
    }

    return [
        'SeluRF' => $SeluRF,
        'form'    => $form->createView(),
    ];
}
```

Comment: `getResult` returns an array, if you select for a single entity use `getSingleResult`. Also: Your query conditions on start and end time are probably switched?

Comment: When add `getSingleResult()` received 500 Internal Server Error: "Call to a member function getSingleResult() on array"

Comment: You should use it instead of your current `getResult` - in your repository function (3rd last row in your upper paste)

Comment: I past it in repository function

Comment: Post the updated function then. You aren't calling `MyQuery` anywhere in your controller - you should make your question coherent.

Comment: public function MyQuery( $selName )
  {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder( 'dg' )
      ->where( 'dg.name= :par1' )
      ->andWhere( 'dg.dateStart >= :now')
      ->andWhere( 'dg.dateEnd < :now')
      ->setParameter( 'par1', $selName )
      ->setParameter( 'now', new \DateTime() )
      ->getQuery()
      ->setMaxResults(1)
      ->getSingleResult()
      ->getResult();
  }

Comment: Your last comment ends with `getResult` - I told you it needs to be `getSingleResult` - what gave you the impression you should use both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getSingleResult` if you don't want your function to return an array but a single Entity:

```
class DictSelRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  /**
   * Function MyQuery
   * @param $selName
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function MyQuery( $selName )
  {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder( 'dg' )
      ->where( 'dg.name= :par1' )
      ->andWhere( 'dg.dateStart >= :now') // This should probably be <= ?
      ->andWhere( 'dg.dateEnd < :now') // This should probably be > (or >=) ?
      ->setParameter( 'par1', $selName )
      ->setParameter( 'now', new \DateTime() )
      ->getQuery()
      ->getSingleResult(); // Replaced getResult with getSingleResult
  }
}
```

Comment: ERROR: `Call to a member function getSingleResult() on array` on line 
**->getSingleResult();**

Comment: `getQuery` does not return an array, I don't think you used this actual code.

Comment: I see code end error in symfony console and add line 

is marked as error

Comment: I still think you're having a `getResult` before that and not using the exact code. In any case: Your question is incoherent (your repository function is called `MyQuery`, which never gets called in the controller - it's called `dictGoalByTypeQuery` there. You're calling getRepository on the DoctrineRegistry itself and not on the EntityManager and, even if that worked, you're storing your EntityRepository in a variable named `$em` - which would generally imply that it's the EntityManager which is stored there, which is not wrong programmatically but makes this Q a lot harder to understand).